# StringReader.ReadLine clears the given string, is there chance to not clean the string?

Tags: c#, string, stringreader

When I am using StringReader.ReadLine to read text from array of strings, it reads it perfectly but it also clears my array,

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(filesGroupList[x]))
       {
          while ((filesGroupList[x] = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
             {
                ...
             }
        }
```

Now, filesGroupList is empty. So if i will want to read data from this string again it will give me null reference exception, so the only way for me is to create a copy of this array before using ReadLine, but is there chance to avoid it? so when StringReaded finished reading the line, my line still stays inside array.

Comment: I cannot understand what are you trying to acheive, it looks very weird

Comment: I am trying read specific info from my string, but I will have to use this string later again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code that you have written, here's an example of what I see it doing:

```
//going to set filesGroupList[x] to a string and then see what happens.
filesGroupList[x] = "First line of string.\nSecond line of string.\n";
//now we go into the using portion.
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(filesGroupList[x]))
{
  //reader has access to the whole string.
  while ((filesGroupList[x] = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    //first time through, filesGroupList[x] is set to "First line of string."
    //second time through, filesGroupLIst[x] is set to "Second line of string."
    Console.WriteLine(filesGroupList[x]);
  }
  //third time through, ReadLine() returns null.
  //filesGroupList[x] is set to null.
  //Code breaks out of while loop.
  Console.WriteLine(filesGroupList[x]); //outputs an empty line.
}
//outside of using, filesGroupList[x] still null.
Console.WriteLine(filesGroupList[x]); //also outputs an empty line.
```

Now, given my other answer where I suggest using line, we'll keep everything the same except for the line portion.

```
//going to set filesGroupList[x] to a string and then see what happens.
filesGroupList[x] = "First line of string.\nSecond line of string.\n";
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(filesGroupList[x]))
{
  //reader has access to the whole string.
  string line;
  while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    //first time through, line is set to "First line of string."
    //second time through, line is set to "Second line of string."
    Console.WriteLine(line);
  }
  //third time through, ReadLine() returns null.
  //line is set to null.
  //filesGroupList[x] is still set to "First line of string.\nSecond line of string.\n"
  Console.WriteLine(line); //outputs an empty line.
  Console.Write(filesGroupList[x]); //outputs whole string (on 2 lines).
}
Console.WriteLine(line); //won't compile. line doesn't exist.
Console.Write(filesGroupList[x]); //outputs whole string (on 2 lines).
```

So I don't think you want to read from `filesGroupList[x]` and then store that in `filesGroupList[x]`. If the string in `filesGroupList[x]` has no end of line characters, you're simply putting that string right back into it (and then putting `null` in your next time through the `while` loop). If the string in `filesGroupList[x]` does have end of line characters, then each time through the `while` loop, you are putting part of the string back into `filesGroupList[x]`, which I don't think is your intention.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Indeed after the using statement the string is empty, it is expected since:

> StringReader.Dispose: Releases all resources used by the TextReader object. (Inherited from TextReader.)

[MSDN Link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx)

The question is *why* you want to do that, it doesn't seems reasonable what you want to do. No without more context info.

---

Your code function perfectly, or you cannot explain yourself, or your problems is in something completely unrelated.

I just tried myself:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] filesGroupList = new string[1];

    int x = 0;

    filesGroupList[x] = "String is here!";

    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(filesGroupList[x]))
    {
        while ((filesGroupList[x] = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the string is here, I just checked");
            Console.WriteLine(filesGroupList[x]);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the output:

> the string is here, I just checked
>
> String is here!

Comment: yes, but try to put Console.WriteLine(filesGroupList[x]); after using statement

Comment: I think I explained why I want to do this:  I will have to use this string later again.

Comment: But why do you need a `StringReader`? Can't you just loop the `filesGroupList` using a foreach?

Answer (score -1):

I think your mistake is right here:

```
while ((filesGroupList[x] = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
```

You are changing the value of `filesGroupList[x]` each time you read and the last time, setting it to `null`.

If instead, you did something like this:

```
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
...
```

Then once you were outside of the using, you would find `filesGroupList[x]` unchanged.

Comment: then i am not reading my filesGroupList but i am reading line, which is empty.

Comment: if reader is build the same way `new StringReader(filesGroupList[x])` then line is set to each line from filesGroupList[x]. It will only be empty after all lines have been read from filesGroupList[x].